# cURL post JSON array

Tags: php, json, curl

Hi I'm having a problem with posting a `JSON` array with `cURL` to my API,

I have this code below for the `cURL` post:

```
$data_string = stripslashes($JSONData);

$ch = curl_init('http://api.webadress.com');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(  
    'Accept: application/json',                                                                                                                                                        
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

It doesn't store/post anything to the API end and the $results is not returning correct,
What is wrong with the code?

A bit from the `JSON`:

```
{
"name": "test",
"type_id": "1",
"css": "#fb-iframe{}#fb-beforelike{}#fb-beforelike-blur{}",
"json": [
    {
        "Canvas": [
            {
                "Settings": {
                    "Page": {
                        "campaignName": "test"
                    }
                },
                "QuizModule": {
                    "Motivation": [],
                    "Questions": [],
                    "Submit_Fields": [
                        {
                            "label": "Name",
                            "name": "txtName",
                            "value": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"user_id": "123"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your $data_string is formatted correctly? could you give us some example data to look at?

Comment: do you control the server you are making the call to? I would check the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] as I find it strange that you used a custom request method (set to POST) instead of just setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: Thanks @mishu but it the CURLOP_POST didn't do any difference in my results! No I'm not controlling the server

Comment: I added an extract from the JSON above that I'm trying to POST with this code, does it seem to be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `$data_string` is not in `field=value` pairs format and thus nothing is parsed in your `$_POST` global.

Since you want to read from the `$_POST` global:

1. you should not set the `content-type`
2. your `$data_string` must be in `field=value` pairs format

The following will work (I have omitted altogether the header part, you should not set the `content-type`):

```
$data_string = stripslashes($JSONData);
$ch = curl_init('http://api.webadress.com');   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('JSONData'=>$data_string));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

If on the other hand you want to access the data as you already send them, then you shouldn't try to read them through `$_POST` but instead use on the server side:

```
$JSONData = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: Thanks, unfurtunately it didn't help with urlencode(). Maybe the problem is at another place. Also I'm generating this JSON file with Jquery so it is never stored anywere, so therefor I'm using the POST

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) it.